# Webpage resubmitting data onto table after refresh [confirm form resubmission]

Tags: forms, refresh, web2py

Whenever I submit the form, it works. If I try to refresh the page it'll ask this:

[image: click to see]

then if I click continue it'll resubmit the data again onto the table. So essentially I'm asking how can I stop it from resubmitting the data into the table once refresh is clicked? can it be stopped? am I missing something here? can I bypass this somehow?

My sqldb table:

[image: table]

> index

```
def index():
if request.vars:
    sqldb.uevent.insert(name=request.vars.name, latitude=request.vars.lat, longitude=request.vars.lng, phone=request.vars.phone, description=request.vars.description)
```

> view

```
<form method="post">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Name of Uevent:</label>
                      <input class="form-control" id="formName" placeholder="Uevent..." name="name">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="formLat" name="lat">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="formLong" name="lng">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Phone:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="formPhone" placeholder="Phone..." name="phone">
                  </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Description of Uevent:</label>
                     <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="formDescription" placeholder="Description..." name="description"></textarea>
                  </div>
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             </form>
```

> model

```
sqldb.define_table('uevent',
               Field('name', label="Name"),
               Field('latitude', 'float', label="Latitude",readable=False),
               Field('longitude', 'float', label="Longitude",readable=False),
               Field('phone', label="Phone"),
               Field('description', 'text' ,label="Description", default="No Description"),
               Field('appropriate', label="Appropriate",writable=False,readable=False))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you should not refresh a browser page after a POST request (e.g., a typical form submission), as you are instructing the browser to re-submit the POST (that is why the browser pops up a warning -- you typically don't want to post the same data multiple times).

On the web2py end, you can prevent the repeated database insert if you use the [`FORM`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#FORM) or [`SQLFORM`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#SQLFORM) helpers. By default, they add a unique `_formkey` field to the form, which protects against CSRF attacks and also prevents multiple submissions of the same form.

If you don't want to use the web2py form helpers, you could code similar logic yourself. Just add a hidden field to the form with a unique key that you also store in the session (a new unique key must be generated every time the page is requested). When the form is submitted, make sure the submitted key matches the value in the session. After the submission, delete the key from the session so any subsequent submissions will be rejected.